# How to select a node which has a specified child directly

Tags: jsoup

I have an html document like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron media">
    <img class="pull-left media-object" >
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="media-heading">xxx</h2>
        <div>
            <em class="icon-time" title="act time"></em> 2015-11-29 14:00 ～ 2015-11-29 18:00
        </div>
        <div class="address">
            <em class="icon-place" title="act place"></em><a target="_blank" href="http://ooo">yyy</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <em class="icon-statistics" title="act count"></em> zzz</div>
            <div>
                <a alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to select the div which has an em.icon-time child 
[select target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4d9N.png)

how to write the selector in jsoup?

if i use: doc.select("div:has(em.icon-time)"), i will get the root element as following snapshot:
[select result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnR34.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way to get the direct parent element of the matching element. But if you only want to solve this particular problem, then try this selector:

> div:has(em.icon-time):not(:has(div))

I simply added the negation `:not(:has(div))` to avoid getting all the parent divs up to the root.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Do u know where can i find a detail document or sample about this kind of nested expression?

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, I don't now of a more detailed document. I usually only have a look at the Jsoup docs at http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax and then play around until I find a combination of selectors and pseudo-selectors that do the trick.